# bookmark+: The bookmark specific jump handlers don't work: `(wrong-type-argument listp bmkp-dired-history)`

Tags: bookmarks

I have `bookmark+` Version: 2020.12.29

When I try to jump to a dired bookmark (`bmkp-dired-jump`), I get the error:

```
In ‘bmkp-dired-jump History’ source: ‘#[0 \304\302\300\305\303$\211\205\0\306\307\310\301""\207 
[nil nil bmkp-dired-history t helm-comp-read-get-candidates nil delete  helm-cr-default] 6]’ 
 (wrong-type-argument listp bmkp-dired-history)
```

When I change the expression:

```
(list (bmkp-read-bookmark-for-type "Dired" alist nil nil 'bmkp-dired-history)
   current-prefix-arg)
```

to

```
(list (bmkp-read-bookmark-for-type "Dired" alist nil nil nil)
   current-prefix-arg)
```

in the function `bmkp-dired-jump`, it works as expected.
I don't understand the use of the symbol `'bmkp-dired-history` since it doesn't seem to be bound anywhere?

Is this a problem of my setup or a problem with `bookmark+` and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 1):

I don't see what you report. For me, it just works.

(But you might want to try the latest version of [Bookmark+](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BookmarkPlus), which is `2021.03.04`, not `2020.12.29`. Download the latest version from [Emacs Wiki Elisp Area](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs?action=elisp-area).)

Do you see the same thing if you start Emacs using `emacs -Q` (no init file), and loading only Bookmark+? If not, bisect your init file to find the culprit.

(If you need to try to debug something, or want to see a better backtrace for `debug-on-error`, then load the *source* files, `*.el`, not byte-compiled files, `*.elc`.)

Symbol `bmkp-dired-history` is passed as the optional arg `HIST`, which is for an Emacs history variable. It is passed to `bookmark-completing-read`, which in turn ultimately passes it to standard Emacs function `completing-read`.

The symbol passed for a history argument need not be bound; that is, it need not yet exist as a variable that has a value. As you enter inputs to calls that specify a given history variable (such as `bmkp-dired-history`) they are added to the list value of that variable. The first time you do so, since the variable is not yet bound Emacs creates it, and binds it to a singleton list with just the value you entered.

This is all standard Emacs behavior.

If you encounter this problem (or some other) when starting Emacs with `emacs -Q` then please report it using `M-x bmkp-send-bug-report`.